# preg_replace allow specific string

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

I have the function:

`$anyNumberClean = preg_replace('/[^0-9.,-E]/', '', $anyNumberDirty);`

I want to modify it to only keep `E` if it is followed by `-0`.

In other words: Only allow `E-0` and not `E-1` or `EA` or any other string containing `E` if `E` is not followed by `-0`.

How to change the function proper?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Positive Lookahead, here is the regular expression that matches `E` only if it is followed by `-0`

```
/E(?=\-0)/
```

Also try this: https://regex101.com/r/wC7pI4/1

**update 1**

Try this regex: `/([\-0-9\.\,]*)(E-0)?([0-9]*)/ug`

Use php function `preg_match` to capture the match result in array.

This regex will break your input into groups. You need to further verify if the input is valid by examing the match result and keep the desired parts.

Comment: Thx Jason! - Can you please complete my code, since I am not sure where to insert '/E(?=\-0)/'.

Comment: What was your regex trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need to clean a string from any character (so only 0-9) except the characters -., and the string 'E-0'.

So allowed: -1.23 or -1.23E-05
Not allowed -1.23A or -1.23E-15

Comment: This will match empty string as well as `EABC` because of `.*`

Comment: @Jason: this gives me  `Unknown modifier 'g'`.

Trying without `ug` resolves in `E`, so it filters everything except `E`.